# Finding question up-vote value history

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, upvotes

Back in the day on Stack Overflow, if I can recall correctly, up-votes on a question were worth 10 points to the user. Now, it is worth 5 points.

Is there someway to find out if I remember this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, until March 2010 question upvotes used to be 10 points; see [Important Reputation Rule Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/):

> Item the first: **question upvotes will now grant only +5 rep instead of +10.*** There is no change to answer upvotes. This will apply retroactively to all users.